# Splitting and modifying the string

Tags: python

I am trying to modify what I think is string. Please help me figure this out!

When I run "print AB", I get the following output:

```
Call(sample=DF, CallData(GT=0/0, AD=[18, 0], DP=18, GQ=99.0, PL=[0.0, 54.0, 255.0]))
```

I would like to modify "0/0" value located after "GT=" and save it back to "AB".

I was going to split this by comma then split by "=" to access it but it does not seem to work and I am lost how to tackle this.

```
comma = AB.split(",")
```

Can someone give me a suggestion?

Comment: What does it output when you do `print type(AB)`?

Comment: *"but it does not seem to work"* - this leaves us guessing; what did you expect it to do, and what did it actually do?

Comment: I found out it is a list. Sorry for being unclear on my question. I will make a new one with clear information.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a lot of work, will a simple string replace do?

```
>>> AB = "Call(sample=DF, CallData(GT=0/0, AD=[18, 0], DP=18, GQ=99.0, PL=[0.0, 54.0, 255.0]))"
>>> print AB
Call(sample=DF, CallData(GT=0/0, AD=[18, 0], DP=18, GQ=99.0, PL=[0.0, 54.0, 255.0]))

>>> AB = AB.replace("GT=0/0", "GT=")
>>> print AB
Call(sample=DF, CallData(GT=, AD=[18, 0], DP=18, GQ=99.0, PL=[0.0, 54.0, 255.0]))
>>>
```